Why does this generating function not work - where is the mistake?
I have to solve the recurrent equation:
$a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1, a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} + a_n = 0$
My approach is quite normal. So let 
$A(x) = a_0+a_1x+...$  be the generating function and 
$Q(x) = 1-x+x^2$  be a polynomial corresponding to the recurrrent equation above. We have 
$A(x)Q(x) = p_0+p_1x+x^2(a_2-a_1+a_0)+...+x^{n+2}(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}+a_n)+...$
Since $a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} + a_n = 0$, coefficients for $x^2, x^3, ...$ are zero. 
Hence, $A(x)=\frac{p_0+p_1x}{1-x+x^2}$, where $p_0, p_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Now we have to find the roots of the denominator and rewrite the expression as a sum of fractions:
$A(x) = \frac{A}{x- \frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}} + \frac{B}{x- \frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}}; A, B \in \mathbb{C}$
Since $\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2} * \frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2} = 1$, it is equivalent to
$A(x) = \frac{A'}{1-\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}x} + \frac{B'}{1-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}x}; A', B' \in \mathbb{C}$. 
Therefore, 
$a_n = A'*(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2})^n + B'*(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2})^n$.
Since $a_0=0, a_1=1$, we get $A'=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}i}, B'=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}i}$ and the formula is: 
$a_n = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}i}*(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2})^n + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}i}*(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2})^n$.
The problem is, it doesn't work. For $n=2$ it produces $2$, but it should be $1$. What am I doing wrong?

The very last step in your solution of solving for $A'$ and $B'$ is wrong. We have these equations when solving for $A'$ and $B'$:
$$a_0=0=A'\cdot 1+B'\cdot 1$$
$$a_1=1=A'\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)+B'\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)$$
From the first equation, we get $A'=-B'$. From the second equation, we then get:
$$
1=A'\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)-A'\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)
$$
Simplify the right side:
$$
1=A'\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)
$$
Simplify further:
$$
1=A'\cdot -\sqrt{3}i
$$
Thus, we have:
$$A'=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}i}$$
and, since $B'=-A'$, we have:
$$B'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}i}$$
You must have added a factor of $2$ somehow when solving for $A'$ and $B'$.

It is better to use variables to represent the roots of $Q$, to reduce the chance of computational error.
I'm not sure why you introduced $p_0$ or $p_1$.  These are unnecessary.  Note that
$$A(x)Q(x) = a_0 + (-a_0 + a_1)x = x,$$ therefore
$$A(x) = \frac{x}{1-x+x^2} = \frac{A}{x-r_1} + \frac{B}{x-r_2}, \tag{1}$$ where $r_1, r_2$ are the roots of $Q$.  (Note I am continuing to use your notation even though we should distinguish the function $A(x)$ from the constant $A$.)  Then we require
$$A+B = 1, \quad r_2 A + r_1 B = 0, \tag{2}$$
hence
$$A = \frac{r_1}{r_1 - r_2}, \quad B = \frac{-r_2}{r_1 - r_2}. \tag{3}$$
Substituting $(3)$ into $(1)$,
$$A(x) = \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1} \left( \frac{1}{1 - x/r_1} - \frac{1}{1 - x/r_2} \right) = \frac{1}{r_2 - r_1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (r_1^{-n} - r_2^{-n}) x^n,  \tag{4}$$
from which it follows that
$$a_n = \frac{r_1^{-n} - r_2^{-n}}{r_2 - r_1}. \tag{5}$$  At this point, it is useful to observe that the product of the roots must be equal to $1$; i.e., $r_1 r_2 = 1$ because $x^2 - x + 1 = (x-r_1)(x-r_2) = x^2 - (r_1 + r_2)x + r_1 r_2$, and equating coefficients on both sides yields this relationship.  Hence
$$a_n = \frac{r_2^n - r_1^n}{r_2 - r_1}. \tag{6}$$
Now we may substitute the roots and simplify; it doesn't matter which root is $r_1$ and which is $r_2$.  We have
$$r_1 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i, \quad r_2 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i,$$
which yields
$$a_n = \frac{(1+i\sqrt{3})^n - (1-i\sqrt{3})^n}{2^n i \sqrt{3}}. \tag{7}$$
Notice how the use of variables until the very end helps us to avoid computational errors.
